# AsyncStorage.multiRemove Not working On logout. in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I am Trying To Clear My All AsyncStore Except "read1","read2". But When I press Logout And then Open App again. I dont get Login Screen. I direct Redirect to second screen. But I remove All Item Except Some. so I think I made some mistakes or multiRemove not working. please help.

here is How I use multiRemove

```
 onPress: () => {
                    AsyncStorage.multiRemove(
                      "id",
                      "doctor_id",
                      "created_time",
                      "is_profile_completed",
                      "otp",
                      "otp_valid_till",
                      "nature",
                      "login_as",
                      "user_name",
                      "read2"
                    );
                       BackHandler.exitApp();
                    
                  },
```

I added that read2 to check whether its clearing or not but its not clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
        .then(keys => AsyncStorage.multiRemove(keys))
        .then(() =>  BackHandler.exitApp(); );
```

async storage work asynchronously so you should have to wait for the work to be done then exit the app. eventually you have to wait for promise to be resolved and add your work in to then block when asynchronously work has been done successfully

Comment: its saying  callback is not a function. (In 'callback(err, keys)', 'callback' is "id")

Comment: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: keys.forEach is not a function. (In 'keys.forEach(function (key) {
          return checkValidInput(key);
        })', 'keys.forEach' is undefined)

Comment: would you please share your code on playground or on expo snack so i could have a good insight what you are trying to do with code ? well key.forEach key isnt a array thats why it showing you key.forEach is not a function.
AsyncStorage.getAllkeys() would give you all the keys in Asyncstorage then on multiRemove just pass those keys.